# Generate output files in separate directory in c using make file

Tags: c, build, makefile

How can i build a c project using makefile that generate intermediate and output files in separate directory other than source?

Current form of my makefile is

```
CC = g++

LDLIBS = -lm

all: test_makefile

test_makefile: file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o test_makefile.o
clean:
    rm test_makefile *.o
```

I want to generate these intermediate files in /build directory. 
Can anyone help me to modify this make file?

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the relative path? `./build/{name}`

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target 'build/file1.o', needed by 'test_makefile'.  Stop.

This is the result when i change path to ./build/{name}

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using Automake (https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) for projects of significant size with separate source and build directories.

Without automake, and considering that by default compilers generate output files in CWD, you can simply create your makefile in the build directory. Here's an example that uses ../ as source directory:

```
all: foo
foo: ../x.cc
    $(CXX) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks for replay
I am a newbie to make 
can you please help me to change my makefile?
i cant really understand ../x.cc
    $(CXX) $< -o $@   these symbols

Comment: do we need x.cc or x.c   ?

Comment: I am trying to create makefile for small project, Is there any option to build intermediate files other than in CWD with a simple makefile ?

Comment: the line: $(CXX) $< -o $@ can be easily changed to $(CXX) $< -o ../build/$@  then the later items, like the link could source their input from the ../build directory.  here is a link to documentation on make: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Sure Shihab, one by one, "foo: ../x.cc" starts a rule to build target "foo" from the dependency list ".../x.cc", i.e. x.cc in the parent directory. As mentioned in my answer, I'm using the parent directory as source directory here.
The second line "$(CXX) $< -o $@" calls the C++ compiler, since CXX usually defaults to "c++". The dependencies from above are passed as first arguments on the command line "$<" and "-o $@" specifies the name of the output file. Make expands "$@" to the name of the rule target, so the entire command as issued by Make will result in this:
    c++ ../x.cc -o foo

Comment: Shihab, about "x.c" vs "x.cc", that depends on whether your source files are written in C which uses ".c" as file extension, or C++ which usually uses ".C", ".cc" or ".cpp". If you are compiling C sources, you need to call the C compiler with $(CC) instead of the C++ compiler $(CXX).